# Extends Dashboard customer for telephone number

Tags: magento2, overrides, class

I'm trying to extend `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info.php` file. I created a module, where I have my custom block, `Info.php`. I want to display the telephone number of the customer after.

```
<?php

namespace Portail\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard;

class Info extends Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info
{
    public function testTxt(){
        return 'bonjour';
    }
}
```

I have added a `di.xml` in etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" type="Portail\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" />
</config>
```

But I have this error : Method invalid `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info::testTxt`

Answer (score 1):

Solution : backslash and ran setup:upgrade

change from

> class Info extends Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info

to

> class Info extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info